# Text always leaves it's container when ever there is space around the text

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to insert an element to an existing element. But each time I insert it, the text inside the element node to be appended will leave the element and stays outside the initial container, I found out that each time I called `.trim()` on it, it won't leave the container.

E.g

```
let txt = "  space around the text  ";
let node = `<span styly="prop:val;">${txt}</span>`;

let div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

div.innerHTML = node;
```

The result of the above code will be:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  space around the text
  <span style="prop:val"></span> //nothing inside the span
</div>
```

If I remove the spaces in the `txt` i.e calling on `.trim()` on the txt it will work as expected.

E.g:

```
let txt = "  space around the text  ";
let node = `<span style="prop:Val;">${txt.trim()}</span>`;

let div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

div.innerHTML = node;
```

The result of the above code will be: (it works fine now)

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <span style="prop:val">space around the text</span>
</div>
```

I haven't experienced such problem, I don't know if it is JavaScript error or Dom parsing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1m8w5jfe/ . Maybe there's some more in your program (or html)?

Comment: I'm using mobile phone to view, can you please screenshot the Dom

Comment: see https://imgur.com/a/54q2DLk

Comment: Thanks, will still go back to the code. Seems there are other factors causing the problem. I will share the solution when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem with my code.

I was matching all new line and replacing them with `<li>` tag, so each time it matches it, it breaks out of the parent container.

Example;

I have an *HTML* code like below.

```
<div style=color=red>
    <span style=color=green>element
        <span style=color=blue> inner </span>
    </span>
        Some texts....
</span>
```

So matching every new line and replacing it with a `<li>` the element `<li>` will cause **HTML** parser to close the first `<span>` causing the text "Some text...." not being able to inherit the style color "green" from it's parent element.

---

The solution to my problem is closing every element before replacing new line with `<li>` as simple as that.

Comment: Why are you replacing new line with `<li>`?

Comment: I was creating a script to highlight HTML, CSS and JavaScript code snippet. So I want every new line to be numbered. So replacing every new line, helps me to number even empty line

Comment: By doing that, you are making your HTML invalid, and could cause rendering issues as you already have noticed. Based on the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), `<li>` are only allowed inside certain other elements. And you can only omit the closing `</li>` tag if it is immediately followed by another `<li>`.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected those invalid codes. Thanks for your concern.